# Suppose that $g$ is isomorphism. Then prove that $f$ is monic and $h$ is epic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, diagram-chasing

$$
\\ 
0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0 \\
0 \to A' \to B' \to C' \to 0
$$
These are exact and they occur a commutative diagram by homomorphism.
$$
g=B\to B'\\
f=A\to A'\\
h=C \to C'
$$
Suppose that $g$ is isomorphism. Then $f$ is monic and $h$ is epic.

To find $f$ is monic I need to find $\ker(f)=\{0\}$. Suppose $a$ is in $\ker(f)$. $$( x= A \to B , x'=A' \to B' , y=B \to C , y'= B' \to C' )$$ 
Also we have $g(b)=y'(a')$. By diagram, $x'f(a)=gx(a)$. $f(a)=0$ ( $a$ is in $\ker f$) then $x'(0)=0$. because $x'$ is homomophism. Then $g(x(a))=0$. it means that $x(a)$ is in $\ker(g)$.

How can I get $a =0$?

if $h$ is epic,then there is $c'$ such that $h(c)=c'$. By diagram , $y'x'(a')=hy(b)=0$.

how can I find $c'$? Can someone help me out, please ?

Comment: What is Kerf?  (or kerf). Please define.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)

Comment: I've edited things a little to show you what MathJax can do for you. You might want to try to continue the process. (You can click "edit" below your question to edit it!)

Comment: Sorry, its edited now. Kerf = kernel of f. Kerg = kernel of g.

Comment: Consider a proof by tedium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close concerning $f$! Let me help you out.

> Consider the following diagram with exact rows
>
> [image]
>   Suppose that $g$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ is monic and $h$ is epic

*Proof.* Let $x\in\ker f$. Then by commutativity $(g\circ\alpha_0)(x)=(\alpha_1\circ f)(x)=0$ and therefore $\alpha_0(x)\in\ker g$. But $g$ is an isomorphism, thus $\ker g=\{0\}$ and so $\alpha_0(x)=0$. As $\alpha_0$ is monic it immediately follows that $x=0$ as desired.

Now, take $x\in C'$. Then, as $\beta_1$ is epic and $g$ is an isomorphism, $\beta_1\circ g$ is epic aswell. So there is $y\in B$ such that $(\beta_1\circ g)(y)=x$. Now, let $z=\beta_0(x)\in C$. By commutativity 
$$h(z)=(h\circ\beta_0)(y)=(\beta_1\circ g)(y)=x$$
Thus $h$ is epic as desired. $\square$

---

> If $g$ is an isomorphism and $h$ is monic, then $f$ is epic.

*Proof.* Take $x\in A'$ and consider $\alpha_1(x)$. Then there is $y\in B$ such that $g(y)=\alpha_1(x)$ as $g$ is an isomorphism. By commutativity $$(h\circ\beta_0)(y)=(\beta_1\circ g)(y)=(\beta_1\circ\alpha_1)(x)=0$$ 
Thus $\beta_0(y)\in\ker h$. But $h$ is monic by assumption and therefore $\beta_0(y)=0$ and $y\in\ker\beta_0$. By exactness there is $z\in A$ such that $\alpha_0(z)=y$. Then it is immediate that 
$$(\alpha_1\circ f)(z)=(g\circ\alpha_0)(z)=g(y)=\alpha_1(x)$$
As $\alpha_1$ is monic we obtain $f(z)=x$ as desired. $\square$

Comment: @mrturho . Thanks ,Sir. I got one more question if u dont mind . 
ı need to show that g is isomooprhism. if h is monic then f is epic. by commutative diagram, hy(b)=y'g(b)=y'x'(a')=0. since h is monic, y(b) is in kernel of h. y(b)=0. it means that b is in kernel of y. by exact sequence, ker(y)=im(x). Then x(a)=b. Since g is isomorphism, g(b)=x'(a'). by exact sequence, x'f(a)=gx(a)=g(b)=x'(a'). from here, how can ı say f(a)=a'. ı dont know x' is epic or not.

Comment: @Wai See my edit.

Comment: @mrturho. Thank you . I got why alpha1 ( it is x' in my solution) is monic. I could not see. Thanks again for ur help.